# How to Create SEGY Header in C#? any packages available?

Tags: c#

I want to create a SEGY 2D seismic file from scratch and did anyone worked on creating segy by setting Binary header and ebcdic header. I don't see any libraries to do the same.

Comment: The code is pretty simple to write.  did you read specification : https://www.seg.org/Portals/0/SEG/News%20and%20Resources/Technical%20Standards/seg_y_rev1.pdf

Comment: Yes, I have understood the segy format. Instead me writing the complete code, may be I take someone help this will reduce time and investment. That is the reason I have asked for any seg writer, All I see is SEGYReader....